# data not inserting in DB using array foreach function in PDO PHP

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach, insert

When I sending the data to the server in PHP with different input and same name I am not able to insert in my database through `foreach` function.
I tried my best and all others functions available on stackoverflow but they all are not helpful for me.

Please help me how to make this fix and what will the real code to achieve my code functions.
as developer console sending data is -

`productID:` `21202,33201,44202,44202,33204`

`Qty:` `1,2,3,4,5`

**PHP**

```
foreach($_POST['productID'] as $product) {
   foreach($_POST['Qty'] as $qty) {
      $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (product,qty) VALUES (:p,:q)");
      $stmt->execute(array(
       ':p' => $product,
       ':q' => $qty 
      ));
   }
}

echo $_POST['productID'];
response is = 21202,33204,332061
```

Comment: Please give us some more information. What does `$_POST` actually contain? Can you add the results of `var_dump($_POST);` to your question? Without that, we have no clue what your code should look like. Show us the data from a working example and a non-working example. Also, when it's not working, do you get any error message or what happens? Have you configured PDO to throw exceptions on errors? That makes it easier to debug queries against the database.

Comment: when I echo POST then response was `21202,33204,332061`

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($_POST)` and add the output to your question. We need to see the complete $_POST array to know what it contains.

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: @Nick I am not able to use foreach function and insert in db with no any error

Comment: That looks like a comma separated string, not an array. Try `foreach(explode(',', $_POST['productID']) as $product) {
   foreach(explode(',', $_POST['Qty']) as $qty) {`

Comment: `echo` is _not_ the same as `var_dump()`. Either way, since that is a comma separated string, you can't iterate through it using foreach.

Comment: You should really call `prepare()` _before_ the loop, then call `execute()` with the new values inside the loop.

Comment: @Nick could you please answer this is properly so I can voteup and understand properly

Comment: My guess is that you have the same issue with `Qty`, but since you haven't added what I asked for, I'm just guessing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson var dump response was `string(17) "21202,51101,44202" `

Comment: I asked for `var_dump($_POST)`, not `var_dump($_POST['productID'])`. I've written the exact code snippet three times now. Just copy/paste what I wrote instead of trying to make your own version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear your input data are comma separated strings of values, not arrays. To iterate over them, you need to convert them to an array using `explode`:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (product,qty) VALUES (:p,:q)");
foreach(explode(',', $_POST['productID']) as $product) {
   foreach(explode(',', $_POST['Qty']) as $qty) {
      $stmt->execute(array(
       ':p' => $product,
       ':q' => $qty 
      ));
   }
}
```

Note that you only need to prepare the statement once, so I've moved that outside the loop. You can also further optimise this code by binding parameters outside the loop:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (product,qty) VALUES (:p,:q)");
$stmt->bindParam(':p', $product);
$stmt->bindParam(':q', $qty);
foreach(explode(',', $_POST['productID']) as $product) {
   foreach(explode(',', $_POST['Qty']) as $qty) {
      $stmt->execute();
   }
}
```

Note that the above code will insert all combinations of `productID` and `Qty` values into the table (as does your original code), but you probably only want the matching values. In that case, use this code:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (product,qty) VALUES (:p,:q)");
$stmt->bindParam(':p', $product);
$stmt->bindParam(':q', $qty);
$quantities = explode(',', $_POST['Qty']);
foreach(explode(',', $_POST['productID']) as $key => $product) {
    $qty = $quantities[$key];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: @JohnCart absolutely, assuming `$con` is a PDO connection

Comment: @JohnCart I've just tested this exact code on my server with `$_POST = array('productID' => '21202,51101,44202', 'Qty' => '4,5,6');` and it inserts 9 rows into the table

Comment: i believe it should insert only three

Comment: @JohnCart please see my latest edit, that will only insert matching values of `ProductID` and `Qty`, so for `$_POST = array('productID' => '21202,51101,44202', 'Qty' => '4,5,6');` it inserts three rows of `21202  4
51101  5
44202  6`

Comment: @Nick Please help when I var_dump I get the response ` ["productID"]=>
  string(17) "21202,21202,21202"
  ["Qty"]=>
  string(5) "1,2,3"`

Comment: What I do then ?

Comment: @JohnCart what do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: @JohnCart with that input data, if you use the last code in my question, it will insert 3 rows: `21202,1`, `21202,2`, `21202,3` in your table. I have tested this code on my own PDO server and it is working fine. The only way it might not work is if you have a unique index on `product`, in which case you will need to group all the quantity values for each product before inserting. However that is a completely different problem to your current question, and if that is the case, you should ask a new one about that.

Comment: thank you @Nick actually I was made one column name as `Unique in my table`

Comment: @JohnCart no worries - I'm glad you got it resolved.